# How to get newly updated data in a cell in a DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I create a table from DefaultTableModel, and then I use table.getModel().setValueAt(value,row,col) to add the 1st value in a cell. However, when I click the mouse on that cell and change the data inside to the 2nd value. and then I get that value back by getValueAt(row,col), it always returns that first value even though on the table the 2nd value is displayed in the cell. What am I wrong?

Hope you understand my messy idea.

Thanks a lot!
//////////////

Thank you for your answer, I have copied the code from the link you gave me and run it. I have a test like this: I modify value at the Cell(0,3) and then try  getting that value out (by click the okButton) But the value is the old, NOT the new one?

Here is the code :

```
package DialogExample;


import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel implements TableModelListener {
private boolean DEBUG = false;
 JTable table;
 JButton okButton;

public JButton getOkButton() {
    okButton = new JButton("OK");
    okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override //// modify value at the Cell(0,3) and then get that value out. 
        /// the value is the old, NOT the new one?????
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int i = (Integer) table.getModel().getValueAt(0, 3);
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    });
    return okButton;
}

public SimpleTableDemo() {
    super(new GridLayout(1, 0));


    String[] columnNames = { "First Name", "Last Name", "Sport",
            "# of Years", "Vegetarian" };

    Object[][] data = {
            { "Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5),
                    new Boolean(false) },
            { "John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true) },
            { "Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2),
                    new Boolean(false) },
            { "Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20),
                    new Boolean(true) },
            { "Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false) } };

    table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

    if (DEBUG) {
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                printDebugData(table);
            }
        });
    }

    // Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    // Add the scroll pane to this panel.
    add(scrollPane);
    add(getOkButton());
}

public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
    int row = e.getFirstRow();
    int column = e.getColumn();
    TableModel model = (TableModel) e.getSource();
    String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
    Object data = model.getValueAt(row, column);

    // Do something with the data...
}

private void printDebugData(JTable table) {
    int numRows = table.getRowCount();
    int numCols = table.getColumnCount();
    javax.swing.table.TableModel model = table.getModel();

    System.out.println("Value of data: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        System.out.print("    row " + i + ":");
        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
            System.out.print("  " + model.getValueAt(i, j));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
}

/**
 * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
 * invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    // Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Create and set up the content pane.
    SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); // content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    // Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    // creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Please post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

- now could be works,
- have to define `TableModel` with proper `ColumnClass`

code

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class SimpleTableDemo extends JPanel implements TableModelListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private boolean DEBUG = false;
    private JTable table;
    private JButton okButton;
    private String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport", "# of Years", "Vegetarian"};
    private Object[][] data = {{"Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), (false)},
        {"John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), (true)},
        {"Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), (false)},
        {"Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), (true)},
        {"Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), (false)}};
    private TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }
    };

    private JButton getOkButton() {
        okButton = new JButton("OK");
        okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                int i = (Integer) table.getModel().getValueAt(0, 3);
                System.out.print(i);
            }
        });
        return okButton;
    }

    public SimpleTableDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        model.addTableModelListener(this);
        table = new JTable(model);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
        add(getOkButton());
    }

    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        int row = e.getFirstRow();
        int column = e.getColumn();
        model = (TableModel) e.getSource();
        String columnName = model.getColumnName(column);
        Object datas = model.getValueAt(row, column);
        System.out.println("Column ---> " + columnName + ", new value is " + datas);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        SimpleTableDemo newContentPane = new SimpleTableDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); // content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do without an SSCCE, but please read the tutorial about [JTables in general](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and, more specific, [model changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange) first.